# Extract text inside XML tags with in Python (while avoiding <p> tags)

Tags: python, regex, xml

I'm working with the NYT corpus in Python and attempting to extract only what's located inside "full_text" class of every .xml article file. For example:

```
<body.content>
      <block class="lead_paragraph">
        <p>LEAD: Two police officers responding to a reported robbery at a Brooklyn tavern early yesterday were themselves held up by the robbers, who took their revolvers and herded them into a back room with patrons, the police said.</p>
      </block>
      <block class="full_text">
        <p>LEAD: Two police officers responding to a reported robbery at a Brooklyn tavern early yesterday were themselves held up by the robbers, who took their revolvers and herded them into a back room with patrons, the police said.</p>
      </block>
```

Ideally, I'd like to parse out only the string, yielding "LEAD: Two police officers responding to a reported robbery..." but I'm unsure of what the best approach would be. Is this something that can be easily parsed by regex? If so, nothing I've attempted seems to work.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `BeautifulSoup` parser also.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> s = '''<body.content>
      <block class="lead_paragraph">
        <p>LEAD: Two police officers responding to a reported robbery at a Brooklyn tavern early yesterday were themselves held up by the robbers, who took their revolvers and herded them into a back room with patrons, the police said.</p>
      </block>
      <block class="full_text">
        <p>LEAD: Two police officers responding to a reported robbery at a Brooklyn tavern early yesterday were themselves held up by the robbers, who took their revolvers and herded them into a back room with patrons, the police said.</p>
      </block>'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> for i in soup.findAll('block', class_="full_text"):
        print(i.text)



LEAD: Two police officers responding to a reported robbery at a Brooklyn tavern early yesterday were themselves held up by the robbers, who took their revolvers and herded them into a back room with patrons, the police said.
```

Comment: This worked great! I was thinking about using beautiful soup, but couldn't quite figure out the syntax for that specific class. Thanks a lot!

Comment: but findAll doesn't work in that way in jsoup, i just tried and got the error `invalid character constant` for `'block'`. do you happen to know what method to use?

Comment: @AvinashRaj [voila](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29739259/parsing-xml-with-jsoup-while-avoiding-p-tags)

Answer (score 0):

> Is this something that can be easily parsed by regex?

[Dont'!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/62138)

Use an xml parser like [lxml](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath).

```
ex = """
<body.content>
      <block class="lead_paragraph">
        <p>LEAD: Two police officers responding to a reported robbery at a Brooklyn tavern early yesterday were themselves held up by the robbers, who took their revolvers and herded them into a back room with patrons, the police said.</p>
      </block>
      <block class="full_text">
        <p>LEAD: Two police officers responding to a reported robbery at a Brooklyn tavern early yesterday were themselves held up by the robbers, who took their revolvers and herded them into a back room with patrons, the police said.</p>
      </block>
</body.content>"""

from lxml import etree
ex = etree.fromstring(ex)
print ex.findtext('./block/p')
```

Output:

```
LEAD: Two police officers responding to a reported robbery at a 
Brooklyn tavern early yesterday were themselves held up by the robbers, who
took their revolvers and herded them into a back room with patrons, the 
police said.
```

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't quite get this to work in my code, but I trust the resource above is invaluable.

Comment: @rutrastone Assumptions were made based on your snippet of XML, but yeah the xpath could change based on what the entire document you are working with.