# parsing xml with jsoup (while avoiding <p> tags)

Tags: java, jsoup

This question is very similar in nature to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29202223/extract-text-inside-xml-tags-with-in-python-while-avoiding-p-tags), but for java instead of python.

```
<body.content>
  <block class="lead_paragraph">
    <p>LEAD: Two police officers responding to a reported robbery at a Brooklyn tavern early yesterday were themselves held up by the robbers, who took their revolvers and herded them into a back room with patrons, the police said.</p>
  </block>
  <block class="full_text">
    <p>LEAD: Two police officers responding to a reported robbery at a Brooklyn tavern early yesterday were themselves held up by the robbers, who took their revolvers and herded them into a back room with patrons, the police said.</p>
  </block>
```

What I'm trying to do is extract the text of the sentence without all the xml formatting, using jsoup.

So I'm looking for

```
LEAD: Two police officers responding to a reported robbery at a Brooklyn tavern early yesterday were themselves held up by the robbers, who took their revolvers and herded them into a back room with patrons, the police said.
```

---

**UPDATE**

In fact my situation is a bit different though, because I've got some additional XML formatting which I'd like to keep, i.e. `<PERSON>`

```
 <block class="full_text">
    <p>SCHEINMAN</PERSON>--<PERSON>Alan</PERSON>. Happy Birthday. Thirteen years, many tears. Loving memories of your smile, humor, and laughter comfort us. You are always in our hearts. Love, <PERSON>Roni</PERSON>, <PERSON>Sandy</PERSON>, <PERSON>Jarret</PERSON>, <PERSON>Greg</PERSON>, <PERSON>Kate</PERSON>, and <PERSON>Auden Gray</PERSON></p>
 </block></body.content></body></nitf>
```

The ideal output would be:

```
SCHEINMAN</PERSON>--<PERSON>Alan</PERSON>. Happy Birthday. Thirteen years, many tears. Loving memories of your smile, humor, and laughter comfort us. You are always in our hearts. Love, <PERSON>Roni</PERSON>, <PERSON>Sandy</PERSON>, <PERSON>Jarret</PERSON>, <PERSON>Greg</PERSON>, <PERSON>Kate</PERSON>, and <PERSON>Auden Gray</PERSON>
```

My attempt so far:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
try 
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  String line = br.readLine();

  while (line != null) 
  {
    sb.append(line);
    sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
    line = br.readLine();
  }
  String everything = sb.toString();

  Document doc = Jsoup.parse(everything);
  String link = doc.select("block.full_text").text();
  System.out.println(link);      
}
finally 
{
  br.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use CSS selectors in [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html).

```
String html = "<body.content>\n"
        + "  <block class=\"lead_paragraph\">\n"
        + "    <p>LEAD: Two police officers responding to a reported robbery at a Brooklyn tavern early yesterday were themselves held up by the robbers, who took their revolvers and herded them into a back room with patrons, the police said.</p>\n"
        + "  </block>\n"
        + "  <block class=\"full_text\">\n"
        + "    <p>LEAD: Two police officers responding to a reported robbery at a Brooklyn tavern early yesterday were themselves held up by the robbers, who took their revolvers and herded them into a back room with patrons, the police said.</p>\n"
        + "  </block>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
String link = doc.select("block.full_text").text();
System.out.println(link);
```

**Output:**

```
LEAD: Two police officers responding to a reported robbery at a Brooklyn tavern early yesterday were themselves held up by the robbers, who took their revolvers and herded them into a back room with patrons, the police said.
```

**Update:**

```
String html = "<block class=\"full_text\">\n"
        + "    <p>SCHEINMAN</PERSON>--<PERSON>Alan</PERSON>. Happy Birthday. Thirteen years, many tears. Loving memories of your smile, humor, and laughter comfort us. You are always in our hearts. Love, <PERSON>Roni</PERSON>, <PERSON>Sandy</PERSON>, <PERSON>Jarret</PERSON>, <PERSON>Greg</PERSON>, <PERSON>Kate</PERSON>, and <PERSON>Auden Gray</PERSON></p></block></body.content></body></nitf>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
String link = doc.select("block.full_text").html();
System.out.println(link);
```

**Output:**

```
<p>SCHEINMAN--
 <person>
  Alan
 </person>. Happy Birthday. Thirteen years, many tears. Loving memories of your smile, humor, and laughter comfort us. You are always in our hearts. Love, 
 <person>
  Roni
 </person>, 
 <person>
  Sandy
 </person>, 
 <person>
  Jarret
 </person>, 
 <person>
  Greg
 </person>, 
 <person>
  Kate
 </person>, and 
 <person>
  Auden Gray
 </person></p>
```

Comment: i added some update, it seems my application is a bit different and i guess that has some effect, i didn't think it would, but apparently does, as it seems that the solution you provided isn't working on the case of my data, please forgive me for not specifying the differences more clearly in my original question

Comment: What's your expected output? it works for me with your updated example. Output produced was `SCHEINMAN--Alan. Happy Birthday. Thirteen years, many tears. Loving memories of your smile, humor, and laughter comfort us. You are always in our hearts. Love, Roni, Sandy, Jarret, Greg, Kate, and Auden Gray`

Comment: that's quite strange, i put those code i'm using, it just outputs nothing. is there any way to keep those `<PERSON>` tags?

Comment: still in my program it outputs nothing. do you have any idea why that could be?